# IE displays Script error on recursive function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hy guys!

I have a recursive function that takes time to perform. The IE is "thinking" that function is like a loop with no end.

What should I do to make IE don't show the error?

Thks guys!

Comment: Wht is da error that the IE is displaying? Also, what is the function look like? No, really, we can't help you in anyway based on the current contents of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, it is a functionality in most browsers to give the user a way out if he visits a webpage with javascript that ties up his cpu for too long and thus kills the browser.

The only way around it, is to performance optimize your code so it goes faster :)

I am assuming the "error" look like this, otherwise my answer is wrong:
[image]

Comment: In thats case, the only solution is to rewrite your code so it is faster, and keep in mind that the threshold for "fast enough" depends on the computer of the user, so aim it for the slowest computer you imagine any of your users will have

Comment: But it isn't a harcore code. It's only getting the newest data in a table.

Comment: No matter how softcore the code is, there is obviously something in there that makes ie not like it :) if you post the code maybe someone can spot the problem for you or suggest optimizations

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in your browser runs in a single thread. If you have some kind of code running (recursive or otherwise) that does not yield to the browser every now and then, the browser will pause the script and ask the user whether they want to stop the code or continue. If this didn't happen there would be no way for the user to regain control (if you like your long-running code is running on the same thread as the UI, that is, the webpage). That's why ajax calls are structured in such a way that your code does not wait (that is, block) for the result, but instead a callback function is, well, called back with the results.

So how do you yield in a long-running piece of code? Several ways (ajax is one example) but the most popular is to use setTimeout in some way. Unfortunately it's just not that easy to explain how to use it without knowing what you are doing exactly. Any small examples I could give would be artificial.

So the strict answer to your question is "rewrite your code into execution chunks such t
hat there's no one chunk that takes a long time to execute".